# Boostrap grid: How to show 3col on a line on desk, 2col on tablet, 1col on mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

How can i show 3 (33.3%) colomns on a line on desktop, 2 (50%) colomns on tablet, 1 (100%) colomns on mobile devices ?

Comment: The documentation explain quite well... http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Like this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/bc8BxqKoxH

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The code will be like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="well"> x
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="well"> x
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="well"> x
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```